# enable_if function when type contains static variable with given name and type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype, enable-if

I am trying to get working the thing described in the title.

```
template <class T>
void foo(const Foo* f) // this is general case template
{

}

// this should work only if T has static variable named _Foo with type const Foo*
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(T::_Foo), const Foo*>::value>::type 
  foo(const Foo* f)
{
  T::_Foo = f;
}
```

But it fails to compile with:

```
error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,void>'
```

Shouldn't it default to the first implementation if enable_if fails ? I mean what am I missing here, could someone please explain to me what is wrong and possibly what is a solution. (I have a feeling that the problem lies in this naive decltype(T::_Foo))

Comment: What does your call look like?

Comment: the SFINAE check is incorrect. It will also detect non-static data members of type `const Foo*` and then later fail non-SFINAEy in the `T::_Foo = f;` code.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, any idea how to form a valid check?

Comment: @AdrianLis you can ensure that `decltype(&T::_Foo)` is not of member pointer type. that would also be true if a static data member overloaded its `operator&`, but since in your case your member is a pointer, which can't overload `operator&`, you are safe with that additional check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only works if there is a deduced template argument involved. You probably need to add a level of indirection and also disable the first method in case `T` *does* have a suitable `_Foo`. Or, as an alternative, I'll show how to lower its priority for overload resolution by using `...` vs. `int`:

```
template <class T>
void foo_impl(const Foo* f, T*, ...) // this is general case template
{

}

// this should work only if T has static variable named _Foo with type const Foo*
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(T::_Foo), const Foo*>::value>::type 
  foo_impl(const Foo* f, T*, int)
{
   T::_Foo = f;
}

template <class T>
void foo(const Foo* f) // this is general case template
{
    return foo_impl(f, (T*)nullptr, 0);
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ac5f8173a67bdb7)

Comment: What if T is not default-constuctible. Can I add just a pointer to T* and give it default value of nullptr?

Comment: @AdrianLis Yes. Fixed.

Comment: I still get the 'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if<false,void>', despite the additional indirection.

Comment: @AdrianLis You are right, there is something else missing. I will update the answer in a minute.

Comment: @DanielFrey i think you shoul use declval.?

Comment: @Koushik Nope, `foo` is actually evaluated.

Comment: @AdrianLis Fixed, including live example.

Comment: @DanielFrey, Ok this kinda sucks because your example works on VS13 Express I installed yesterday just for test, but I work on VS2012 with Nov CTP and I guess there must be yet another bug in the compiler because it still fails to compile even with the code you provided above. Thanks anyway.